# Filtering mailgun event poll with unix time stamp

Tags: php, mailgun

I am trying to pull mailgun events from the past 0.5 hours.

It does not filter correctly, and always sends me back the max 300 events, where no events actualy took place in the past 0.5 hours when i polled the api

Any ideas how to set this criteria correctly?
Moreover, how do i take time zone into concederation in order to make sure i actually pull the past 0.5 hours of my time zone?
(Asia/Jerusalem)

Thanks
Here is my code snippet:

```
$begin = time() - (0.5*60*60);
$logger->info_new('Pulling mailgun events since  '.gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $begin)); 
$logger->info_new($mailGunToken); 
$eventsToPull =array('failed', 'delivered');
# Instantiate the client.
$domain      = '********************';
$apiRoot      = '*************************';
$mgClient    = Mailgun::create($mailGunToken, $apiRoot);
foreach ($eventsToPull as $eventToPull){
    try{
        $logger->info_new('polling '.$eventToPull); 
        $queryString = array(
            'begin'        =>$begin,
            'ascending'    => 'no',
            'pretty'       => 'yes',
            'event'    => $eventToPull,
            'limit'     =>300
        );
        # Issue the call to the client.
        $result = $mgClient->events()->get($domain, $queryString);
        $logger->info_new('Fetched '.count($result->getItems()). ' events');
        continue;
    }catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        echo ('Cought RuntimeException '.$e->getMessage());
    }catch(Exception  $ex){
        echo ('Cought Exception '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $logger->info_new('---END EVENT TYPE-----');
}
```

Eventualy i sovled by using ascending= yes and RFC date time formated string:

```
$hoursInterval = 0.5;
$start = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime();
$start->setTimestamp(strtotime("-".($hoursInterval*60)." minutes"));
$begin = $start->format(DateTime::RFC2822);
$end = $end->format(DateTime::RFC2822);
$logger->info_new('Pulling mailgun events since  '.$begin. ' untill '.$end); 
$eventsToPull =array('failed', 'delivered');
# Instantiate the client.
$domain      = '********************';
$apiRoot      = '*************************';
$mgClient    = Mailgun::create($mailGunToken, $apiRoot);
foreach ($eventsToPull as $eventToPull){
    try{
        $queryString = array(
            'begin'        =>$begin,
            'end'        =>$end,
            'ascending'    => 'yes',
            'pretty'       => 'yes',
            'event'    => $eventToPull,
            'limit'     =>300
        );
        # Issue the call to the client.
        $result = $mgClient->events()->get($domain, $queryString);
        $logger->info_new('Fetched '.count($result->getItems()). ' events');
        continue;
    }catch (RuntimeException $e) {
        echo ('Cought RuntimeException '.$e->getMessage());
    }catch(Exception  $ex){
        echo ('Cought Exception '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $logger->info_new('---END EVENT TYPE-----');
}
```

Comment: I found the issue for the events count issue, i needed to define "ascending" as yes. Still need assistance with the time zone issue, i need to make sure i am pulling the events from the past 0.5 hours, at my time zone.